# Trying to use jq to update a value with a variable path

Tags: json, path, jq

I'm trying to pass a JSON path into jq as a variable to update a value. this works great:

```
jq '.Resources.lc.Properties.UserData."Fn::Base64" = "HHH"' my_data.json
```

I can't get any combination like this to work:

```
 KEY='.Resources.lc.Properties.UserData."Fn::Base64"'
  jq --arg p "$KEY" '$p = "HHH"' my_data.json
```

n

jq: error (at my_data.json:470): Invalid path expression with result ".Resources.lc.Properties....

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
KEY='.Resources.lc.Properties.UserData."Fn::Base64"'
jq "$KEY"' = "HHH"' my_data.json
```

Comment: Shell-based string-interpolation is generally deprecated as it is fragile at best.

Comment: Yeah, don't generate programs from using sh. At the very least, you could have exported the var and used `ENV`

Comment: `KEY="$KEY" jq ...` would also do it in the bash/bash-like world.

Comment: @peak Can you give a specific exmaple to explain why `it is fragile` in OP's context ?

Answer (score 3):

The recommended approach here is to pass in the path as an array if possible, so that `setpath` can be used:

```
KEY='["Resources", "lc", "Properties", "UserData", "Fn::Base64"]'
jq --argjson p "$KEY" 'setpath( $p; "HHH")' my_data.json
```

If that is not possible, next best would probably be to parse your $KEY string
with the inner double-quotation-marks removed:

```
KEY='.Resources.lc.Properties.UserData.Fn::Base64'
jq -n --arg p "$KEY" 'setpath( $p|split(".")[1:]; "HHH")' my_data.json
```

Next to next-best would be to strip the inner double-quotation-marks,
e.g. in the shell or using jq

```
KEY='.Resources.lc.Properties.UserData.Fn::Base64'
jq -n --arg p "$KEY" '
  setpath( $p|gsub("\"";"")|split(".")[1:]; "HHH")
' my_data.json
```