# JSON from flat key-value pair to nested object

Tags: json, jq

How can I change a flat key-value pair (with concatenated key) to a nested group. I want to split a key at the `___` and use the new sub-key as key of the nested object.

I have tried `map` and `split("___")` and the operator `|=` but was not able to get it, with `jq`

Source (Input) file, with flat key-value pair

```json
{
  "key1___subkey1-2-foo": "Value 1a",
  "key1___subkey1-2-bar": "Value 1b",
  "key2___subkey2-2___subkey2-3": "Value 2, Level 3",
  "key3": "Value 3"
}
```

Target format, as nested object

```json
{
  "key1": {
      "subkey1-2-foo": "Value 1a",
      "subkey1-2-bar": "Value 1b"
  },
  "key2": {
      "subkey2-2": {
        "subkey2-3": "Value 2, Level 3"
      }
  },
  "key3": "Value 3"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use jq to update a value with a variable path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69142882/trying-to-use-jq-to-update-a-value-with-a-variable-path)

Comment: Not really. Here I just the `setpath` as new function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq 'to_entries | map(.key |= split("___")) | reduce .[] as $obj({}; setpath($obj.key; $obj.value))'
```

The `reduce` builds up the object by applying `setpath` with input element's key/value in turn

Comment: Wow, thanks I have not worked with `reduce` before. Great.